# Anko Logging with verbose and debug isn't working

Tags: android, kotlin, anko

I'm trying to use [Anko Commons – Logging](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/wiki/Anko-Commons-%E2%80%93-Logging#trait-like-style)

but for some reason the verbose and debug not showing on the logcat

however, when I use Log.d it works as expected.

when I'm trying this code

```
verbose("-------------verbose--------------")
debug("-------------debug--------------")
info("-------------info--------------")
warn("-------------warn--------------")
error("-------------error--------------")
wtf("-------------wtf--------------")
```

the log logcat is as following
[image]

I'm using Anko 0.10.0 android studio 3.0 canary-5

when I tried to search for a solution I found [this one](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/issues/230)

> All Log.* will log to logcat regardless of what the current log level is. However, AnkoLogger.* will only log to logcat when its log level is loggable.

but I don't know how to change the log level, and if even it's my problem is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out The default log level is INFO.

From the ADB shell, you can change the log level to DEBUG, VERBOSE etc. using this command:

```
setprop  log.tag.MyApp  DEBUG
```

so As far as know by AnkoLogger uses `Log.isLoggable()` under the hood which ignores `VERBOSE` and `DEBUG` log levels by default.

for more info you can read more about it [here](https://mobiarch.wordpress.com/2012/05/11/proper-logging-from-android-application/)